# MS Access 2010 VBA

Tags: vba

I have the formula below but the AND part of formula not recognized.  Can anyone take a look and provide the proper version?

```
If DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "'") > 6 Or _
        DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "' And _
        [DMax P/N]='" & DLookup("[DMS P/N]", "InventoryList", "Category In('PC','Terminal')") & "'") > 3 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "'") > 6 Or _
        DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "' And " _
        " [DMax P/N]='" & DLookup("[DMS P/N]", "InventoryList", "Category In('PC','Terminal')") & "'") > 3 Then
```

I don't have VBA open now, but try this, the second row wasn't ended correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.  For some reason it didnt like the underscore separating two strings within DCount, but if you move it to right before the & then I dont get the "list separator or )" error.

```
            If DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "'") > 6 Or _
            DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "' And [DMax P/N]='" _
            & DLookup("[DMS P/N]", "InventoryList", "Category In('PC','Terminal')") & "'") > 3 Then
```

how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo;
You do not mention whether this is a formula in a textbox on a form or report; or
if you are writing VBA code. My answer would for these 2 situations would be very different.
Generally, when I see people using old (Access 2003) functions, it is to be able to write everything in the form.
So, I will assume this is the case.

There are several issues:
1) You are using SQL Syntax("Category In()") as your third parameter in the MS DLookUp function (..."Category In('PC','Terminal')...).
I can find no mention of Microsoft supporting this cross-language expression. 
Also, the DLookup function, as defined by MS returns a single value. 
As you have it written, you seem to be asking the engine to look for multiple records.
Check out this Statement I copied from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786: 
The DLookup() function returns one value from a single field even if more than one record satisfies the criteria. 
If no record satisfies the criteria, or if the domain contains no records, DLookup() returns a Null.

So, what if your expression returns a Null value? An English tanslation of your second
DCount Function would be something like this:
Give me the number of records in AssetTagTable Where the column "SerialNumber" = 1732 
AND the Column "[DMax P/N]" = Null. Then compare that number of records to the number 3.
Do you see the issue?

2) When grappling with unexpected results, it is always a good idea to simplify code and assign values to variables, 
or in your case, say, to textboxes.
So, place 2 text boxes on your form and assign a value to each.
E.G. 
Create 2 textboxes: txtNumRecs, and txtCategory
To the textbox txtNumRecs, assign this value: 
DCount("*", "AssetTagTable", "SerialNumber='" & Me.SerialNumber & "'").
To the textbox txtCategory, assign this value: 
DLookup("[DMS P/N]", "InventoryList", "Category='PC' OR Category='Terminal')")
Run your Form.
The first textbox will have a value representing the number of records where SerialNumber = Me.SerialNumber.
You may be surprized at the value found in the second textbox. Consider that a general SQL lookup of all records where 
Category = 'PC' OR Category = 'Terminal' could return many records. Since we know that THIS function will
only return 1 record, how can we possibly know which one of all the possibile records it will return? 
Let's say it returns the [DMS P/N] value for a record where Category='PC', but the first [DMS P/N] value you 
reference is for a record where Category='Terminal'. Or vice-versa. 
This part of your condition check may never return True.

If indeed you wish to examine all the records in InventoryList where Category='PC' OR Category='Terminal',
and to compare the [DMS P/N] value of each to your value, then you must write a function or 2 in VBA to handle this.
If that is beyond your code-writing capabilities, you may contact me for a professional consult.